# Android - Passing View from Activity to AsyncTask class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

**MainActivity.java:**

```
private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args) {
        return cd.isConnectingToInternet();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean th) {
        if (th == true) {
            new RemoteLoader(MainActivity.this).execute();
        }
    }
}
```

**RemoteLoader.java:**

```
public class RemoteLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    private View view;

    public RemoteLoader(View context){
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... Pages) {
             // do in bg
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Set title into TextView
        TextView txttitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtProtip);
        txttitle.setText(protip);
    }

}
```

I'm trying to execute `RemoteLoader` class from `MainActivity`. But in RemoteLoader contains something that needs to inflate the Main layout.

How do I pass the Layout from MainActivity to RemoteLoader in this case?

Comment: why not use a interface as a callback to the activity ans set the text to textview in activity itself

Comment: Okay, I'm too rookie at this. How do I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752073/how-do-i-return-a-boolean-from-asynctask. check the answer by blackbelt

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20791697/507905
I have answered it here, pls check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass an Activity to the RemoteLoader instead of View as follows

```
private WeakReference<Activity> activity;

public RemoteLoader(Activity context){
    this.activity = new WeakReference<Activity>(context);
}
```

**Update:** Using weak reference to prevent possible memory leaks.

Comment: Well, this one works, but is this what you meant by Activity leaking @koljaTM? I mean calling a whole activity to a class sounds like a big task here.

Comment: Thank you Dehan and Amulya for the updated answer. I'll explore more on RoboSpice too.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with this is that in case of e.g. an orientation change during the loading process the activity is recreated and the view will no longer be valid. You risk leaking the activity. Also, the view that you try to write to will no longer be the one visible.

Take a look at the Robospice documentation for understanding the basic problem:
https://github.com/octo-online/robospice/wiki/Understand-the-basics-of-RoboSpice-in-30-seconds
This is one of the trickier parts about Android.

Answer (score 2):

#### Use this code for RemoteLoader:--

```
public class RemoteLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

LayoutInflater inflater;
int layoutResId;

public RemoteLoader(View context,int layoutResId){
    this.view = view;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.layoutResId = layoutResId;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... Pages) {
         // do in bg
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // Set title into TextView
    View yourLayout = inflater.inflate(layoutResId, null);
    TextView txttitle = (TextView) yourLayout.findViewById(R.id.txtProtip);
    txttitle.setText(protip);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the TextView reference to the async task class through constructor

```
public class RemoteLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    TextView txtTitle;

    public RemoteLoader(TextView txtTitle){
        this.txtTitle = txtTitle;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... Pages) {
             // do in bg
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Set title into TextView
        txttitle.setText(protip);
    }

}
```

in your main activity execute the async task as follwos

```
TextView txttitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtProtip);
new RemoteLoader(txttitle).execute();
```

if you want to execute this async task from another async task, then pass the textView reference through that from the MainActivity